# Asp.Net get value from popup window in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, user-controls

I am using a user control and I need to call a popup, which asks a question, and I need to send the response (true or false) back to the user control that invokes the popup.  I declared a hidden field to store the value in it from client-side so I can have access to it from the code behind and then execute further code.  I have the following code:

ASP.Net

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function confirmNoCallList() {
            debugger;
            var resp = confirm("¿Seguro/a que desea agregar a este subscriptor a la 
                       lista de 'No Llamar'?");

            window.opener.document.getElementById('hfAddToNoCallList').value = resp;
        }
</script>


<ajax:TabContainer ID="tbcMyProfile" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="0" Width="500px">
        <ajax:TabPanel ID="tbpInfoCta" runat="server" HeaderText="Información de mi
                           Cuenta">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hfAddToNoCallList" runat="server" />
.
.
.
```

I am getting an error when the function hits the window.opener line.  Any ideas on how to do this the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get the dynamic `ClientID` at runtime or pass it to a function and an arg that can then find it:

```
document.getElementById('<%= hfAddToNoCallList.ClientID"%>').value = resp;
```

or

```
   function confirmNoCallList(hiddenField) {
        debugger;
        var resp = confirm("¿Seguro/a que desea agregar a este subscriptor a la 
                   lista de 'No Llamar'?");

        document.getElementById(hiddenField).value = resp;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks!! both ways are exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

`window.opener` gives you a reference to the browser window that called `window.open(...)` to create the current window. If you're not calling `window.open` then opener will be null.

In the code snippet you've posted, the JavaScript and hidden field are in the same document. Try removing `window.opener.` from the line `window.opener.document.getElementById ...`

Comment: I get the following error if I do that: Unable to set value of the property 'value': object is null or undefined